# How to store child classes in vector and override parent function

Tags: c++, oop, sdl-2

I am trying to code the js super-mario-series from the great YouTube channel "meth meth method" in c++ and SDL2.

Now I am stuck on Episode 04 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rBOUyRGQuU

I am trying to create an `Entity` class which has a vector of a `Trait` class. I want to create many different classes which inherit from `Trait` and store them in the vector. I want to call the subclasses update function and not the original Trait update function.

```
// -- Entity.h -----------------------------------

class Entity {
private:
    Vec2 vel;
    std::vector<Trait*> traits;

public:
    Vec2 pos;
    // Constructor & Destructor
    Entity(void);   
    ~Entity(void);

    void addTrait(Trait* nTrait);

    void update();
};

// -- Entity.cpp -----------------------------------

void Entity::addTrait(Trait* newTrait) { 
    this->traits.push_back( newTrait );
}

void Entity::update() {

    for ( Trait* trait : this->traits ) {
        trait->update(  );
    }    
}
```

```
// -- Trait.h -----------------------------------
class Trait {
private:
    std::string name;
public:
    // Constructor & Destructor
    Trait(std::string aname );
    ~Trait(void);

    void update( void );
};
// -- Trait.cpp -----------------------------------
void Trait::update(  ) {
    printf("Trait update\n");
}
```

And a Velocity.h sub-classs from Trait

```
// -- Velocity.h -----------------------------------
class Velocity : public Trait {
private:
public:
    // Constructor & Destructor
    Velocity(std::string aname);
    ~Velocity(void);

    void update(Entity *entity);
};
// -- Velocity.cpp -----------------------------------
void Velocity::update(Entity *entity ) {
    printf("Velocity update\n");
    entity->setPos(0, 0);
}
```

I tried many different Version, and got different errors. Now I got it working, bit when I add a velocity trait to an entity and call the update method of the entity (which loops through all traits) only the update function gets called from the parent Trait class (which prints "Trait Update" and not "Velocity Update").

main.cpp

```
    Entity *mario = new Entity();

    mario->setPos( 64, 180 );
    mario->setVel(  2, -2 );

    Velocity* velTrait = new Velocity("velocity");
    mario->addTrait(velTrait);

    mario->update();
```

And a second Question is, that I want to give the velocity update function a pointer to the entity, so that I can change the entities position etc ...

Comment: Stay clear of the crystal meth meth method.

Comment: @xpnimi Have you considered actually *learning* C++ (it takes a couple of years) rather than just following random youtube tutorials?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I am trying to learning c++ on the side, and i think it is a good exercise to port code from one language to an other - its not a random yt video at all. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to create many different classes which inherit from `Trait` and store them in the vector. I want to call the subclasses update function and not the original `Trait` update function.

To get what you want, use a `virtual` method:

```
virtual void update( void );
```

For more details, I suggest that you study about polymorphism and virtual functions.

Comment: Yes I tried that, but where exactly doese the virtual keyword go? only to Trait.h update??

Comment: if I add `virtual` to the Trait update function, the velocity update func still doesn't get called.

Comment: got it working, the velocity update func has to be declared the same way as the traits velocity func.

Comment: @xpnimi yes it does. And in C++11 and later, you can (and should) mark a descendant class method as `override` to let the compiler validate whether the descendant method actually overrides a base class method or not: `void update(void) override;` Without the `override`, no such validation is performed, which is why you missed that mistake when you first added `virtual`

Comment: @RemyLebeau how can I pass an Entity to any trait of the traits vector inside the entity update func loop? If I add Entity.h to Trait.h I get quite a lot of errors, and I think it is a conflict because both classes refer to themselves ...

Comment: @xpnimi You would indeed have to change the `Trait::update()` method to take an `Entity*` as input, so that `Velocity::update()` can then do the same. But then you run into a classic circular reference problem, which is solved by using pointers (which you already are) and [forward declarations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class#Forward_declaration) (which is what you are missing).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you - that helped a lot, got it working!